# Can I enlarge/reduce \skip\footins on single page? (similar to \enlargethispage)

Tags: footnotes, margins

Is there a way to reduce or enlarge `\skip\footins` on a single page? So that on the next page, the value goes back to normal?

I'm looking for something similar to `\enlargethispage`, but which does not move the bottom margin but rather the space between text and footnotes.

**Edit (MWE):**

All right, here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Lets have a very large vertical space between text and footnotes: 
\setlength{\skip\footins}{4\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{This is a footnote} 
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

By default, the result is this:

[image]

What I'm looking for is a way of saying something like

```
\onthispage\setlength{\skip\footins}{5\baselineskip}
```

in order to move the one line to the next page. (I know about widow-/orphan control but this does not solve my specific problem).

What I *could* do is `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}`. However, this would move the footnotes upwards. Instead of enlarging the page, I would like to enlarge (or shrik) only the white room between text and footnotes on that page.

Comment: Probably a pseudo-automated way with `afterpage` is not to your liking (as it should be avoided in productive environments eitherway), is it?

Comment: you can just set it and set it back (with a bit of care over when you do that relative to the page ]break)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you post an example? I was unable to make this work.

Comment: I think _you_ have to put a minimal working example which reproduces your problem.

Comment: `\skip\footins` (space between text and footnotes) by default is `\bigskipamount` which is `12pt plus 0.4pt minus 0.4pt` so it's near `\baselineskip`. I don't think reducing it will help you enlarging the text heigh. may be you want to reduce `\footskip` (space between text and footer)

Comment: I added an MWE now to make more clear what I would like to achieve.

Comment: `\clubpenalty=10000` will move the last line (first of a new paragraph) to the next page.

Comment: As I stated in the text, I am not interested in solutions that use orphan/widow penalties. my real situation is of course more complex than this MWE.